# program in c++ that only reads numeric values of a string variable. but not working

Tags: c++, string, c++11

I tried to create a program in c++ that should only reads numeric values of a string variable. But it does not seem to work. Can anyone tell me why?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string str = "11111111111";

     for(unsigned i = 0; i<=str.length(); i++) {
        if(str.at(i)!='0' || str.at(i)!='1' ||str.at(i)!='2' ||str.at(i)!='3' ||
           str.at(i)!='4' || str.at(i)!='5' ||str.at(i)!='6' ||str.at(i)!='7' ||
           str.at(i)!='8' || str.at(i)!='9' ||
           str.at(i)!='-' ) {
          cout << "Invalid Phone Number!" << endl;
          cout << str.at(i);
        break;
        }
     }
    cout << str;

}
```

Comment: what is wrong exactly? I think it compiles fine and give at least some output

Comment: There is no compiler error, it always break the for loop after read the first value, even if the string is numeric.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for(unsigned i = 0; i<=str.length(); i++)
```

change the comparison to `i < str.length()`, and fix the logic:

```
for (unsigned i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) 
{
    if (str[i] < '0' || str[i] > '9')
    {
        if (str[i] != '-')
        {
            cout << str[i] << "\n";
            cout << "Invalid Phone Number!" << endl;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're welcome. If your question has been answered click the large check mark to accept the answer and close this issue http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235

Answer (score 2):

You could use regex:

```
#include <regex>

std::string str = "11111111111";

if (false == std::regex_match(str, std::regex("[-0-9]+")))
{
  std::cout << "Invalid Phone Number!\n";
}
```